# Does C++11 "auto" keyword retrieve "cv-qualifier" at all? I've got conflict samples

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, auto

It's said the "auto" doesn't retrieve cv-qualifier, so I did an experiment:

```
const int i = 0;
auto r1 = i;
auto& r2 = i;
r1 = 3;//ok
r2= 3;//compilation error
```

Seems when constructing a value, cv-qualifier is not with the new variable, but used with reference "&", the cv-qualifier is with it. Why is that, does auto retrieves "cv-qualifier" at all?

Comment: Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU

Comment: You'd get the same effect with a pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`auto` deduction works the same as template deduction for most cases. Just `auto` drops all *cv*-qualifiers, but `auto&` maintains the *cv*-qualifications of the referred type. If `auto&` dropped the qualifiers, you would be able to take a non-const reference to a const object, which would be bad! This works exactly the same way as:

```
template <class T> deduce(T );
template <class T> deduce_ref(T& );

deduce(i);     // calls deduce<int>
deduce_ref(i); // calls deduce<int const>
```

Since `r2` is a reference to `const int`, you can't assign to it. But `r1` is just a copy of `i`.

Comment: Is there a source for the part "auto& maintains the cv-qualifications of the referred type"? I saw it and use this but would love to know if it is specified somewhere in cpp standard or reference. Thanks